# how to rank the characteristic of cluster in r

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, rank

This is the result of cluster analysis through the k-means function.

```
>weseg2<-read.csv("WE_SEG DATA.csv",header=TRUE)

>training.data2<-scale(weseg2)

>aaaa<-kmeans(training.data2, centers=4, iter.max=10000, nstart=20)
```

I want to know what characteristics each cluster has.
So I got the average of each variable by clusters.
this is my code that calculate the mean of variables.

mean of first cluster

```
>rank1<-colMeans(training.data2[aaaa$cluster==1,])
```

mean of second cluster

```
>rank2<-colMeans(training.data2[aaaa$cluster==2,])
```

mean of third cluster

```
>rank3<-colMeans(training.data2[aaaa$cluster==3,])
```

mean of fourth cluster

```
>rank4<-colMeans(training.data2[aaaa$cluster==4,])
```

If so,what code should be entered so taht it can rank the clusters for each variable? 
For example, if you have the variables a,b and c, you have rank of four clusters in the a variable, and rank of four clusters in the b and c variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the apply and rank function.
like this

```
>rank5<-cbind(rank1,rank2,rank3,rank4)
>apply(rank5,1,rank)
```

Then, you can get a rank of columns.
And if you want to get rank as decrease, use the order() function.

good luck.